# What is the difference between ng and ng2 in angular 5?

Tags: angular

Im new to Angular, In the Angular 5 cli there are two versions - ng and ng2. What is the difference between the two and which one should we use for application development. I have looked at the angular documentation at angular.io. However there is no mention of the ng2 command.

Do the ng new app and ng2 new app commands have any differences in terms of the bootstrap code they generate ?

Comment: What version of the Angular CLI are you using? (*Note: there is a difference between Angular and the Angular CLI*) I don't see an `ng2` command in the source code on GitHub and don't see one on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

When Angular first came out, it was called AngularJS (abbreviated as ng).
There was a major revamp in Angular 2 (thus ng2).

Everything released Angular 2 onwards is backwards compatible. However, if you want to migrate from Angular 1.x to anything after will require a major re-write.

The new web technologies like Angular and React are not even a decade old and have evolved a lot. With Angular 2, things have gotten a lot simpler and now that Angular has found a stable direction, they simply call it Angular and mostly everything you do now will be using `ng` and not worry about the versions. At least, if you are looking to work on the latest stable release.